# Retrieving Integer value from SQlite database

Tags: sqlite

I have a problem with retrieving an Integer value from SQLite db. I have an Integer illnessid stored in db. In my Illness class I have declared it as NSNumber *illnessid.

When reading from database,I do

```
NSNumber *illid = [NSNumber numberWithInt:(int)sqlite3_column_text(compiledStatement, 0)];
..........
[listContent addObject:[Illness illnessWithid:illid illness:illness defn:definition]];
```

where listcontent is NSMutable array.

Now I pass the Illness object to another class and try to retrieve the illnessid to query the database.

```
NSNumber *myno = illness.illnessid;
NSInteger illid = [myno integerValue];
```

but this illid is not the integer value stored in db. I need help with this!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are pulling the value from the SQLite database as a `char *` and attempting to explicitly cast it to an `int`.  This is not possible. As an alternative, simply pull the value directly as an `int`.

Change this line...

```
NSNumber *illid = [NSNumber numberWithInt:(int)sqlite3_column_text(compiledStatement, 0)];
```

to ...

```
NSNumber *illid = [NSNumber numberWithInt:sqlite3_column_int(compiledStatement, 0)];
```